# Where is the Silverlight Calendar Control?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, silverlight, xaml

Just playing around with the now released Silverlight 2.0.  I'm trying to put a simple Calendar in a control.  However the project doesn't seem to know what I'm talking about:-

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyFirstSL2.Test"
 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
>
  <Grid Background="#FF5C7590">
    <Calendar />
  </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Visual Studio 2008 just puts blue line under the Calendar saying the type Calendar not found.  Do I need to add an assembly? Which one? Do I need to add another namespace to the Xaml?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The calendar control is an SDK control in the assembly System.Windows.Controls namespace -- look at %program files%\Microsoft SDKs\Silverlight\v2.0\Libraries\Client  add a namespace to your xaml (after you add a reference):

```
xmlns:basics="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls"
```

Then to use:

```
<basics:Calendar />
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

add a reference to

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Silverlight\v2.0\Libraries\Client

system.windows.controls.dll

Use Expressions Blend or VS2008 SP1 to add the control to the UI

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure there's no calendar control in Silverlight that is analogous to the ASP.Net control or the windows forms control.  I'm pretty sure there's not a pre-packaged control like that for WPF, either.

Comment: Haha.  Ok, so I guess there is one :)

Comment: Microsoft has released one for WPF too. Check CodePlex.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to figure out how the toolkit allows for an embeded calendar control I created a custom control here http://slcalendarcontrol.codeplex.com/ check it out.